# How to choose specific Abyssalite to insulate walls or pipes?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

To insulate pipes, I would like to use a specific [Abyssalite](http://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Abyssalite) with the correct temperature. It seems, that the temperature will be "remembered" from the place of origin. You can see that in the temperature overlay.

How can I choose a "cold" Abyssalite to cool down a pipe and prevent the use of "hot" Abyssalite for this purpose?

Answer (score 4):

You can't choose the temperature of the materials you are using to build.

What you can do is:

- Mine the desired Abyssalite and store it in a designated Compactor (use sweep only, choose only Abyssalite to be stored and isolate the place with a mechanized airlock and proper access control)
- Move the Abyssalite to the place you want to use it with the same techniques as above
- Build your pipes, again with proper control : lock up the area to ensure that no Abyssalite goes in except the one you choose.

but if you only want insulate pipes, why not using some insulated pipes ?

Comment: I try to cool down the too hot polluted water on the way to my aquatic farm tiles. This is useless, if the Abyssalite temperature is higher then the water in the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter.  Abyssalite is so poor at conducting heat that you can build scorching hot pipes out of it in a cold biome and it will never do anything.

Insulated pipes (like insulated tiles) use twice the material and allow for 20% of the heat transfer through it.  With Abyssalite this is completely brokenly overpowered for heat transfer.